# Environment variable to boost root that will work in both Windows and Linux in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, environment-variables, cross-compiling

I was attempting to make a secondary set of var paths for Linux but as it turns out, `/` auto-resolves to `C:/` in Eclipse. Is this a safe intended use or a happy accident?

```
BOOST_ROOT =            /boost_1_55_0
GCC C++ include path:   ${BOOST_ROOT}
MinGW C++ library path: ${BOOST_ROOT}\stage\lib
```

[image: two boost include paths]

It seems to work and does compile fine (only tested Win) but seems like it may not be an intentional feature.

The old `BOOST_ROOT = C:/boost_1_55_0` is also shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this by moving boost into the workspace directory and using the ${workspace_loc} Eclipse variable to reference it.